# If there are 8 outcomes what is the probability that in 8 "rolls" I get a different outcome?

Tags: probability

There a game that when you kill a boss it will drop 8 different outcomes.

Their chance is the same so 1/8 = chance to get an outcome.

Now, I want to know what is the chance that in 8 "rolls" I get all different outcomes.

I thought of this:

```
((8/8)*(7/8)*(6/8)*(5/8)*(4/8)*(3/8)*(2/8)*(1/8))*100%
```

And the result is 0,240325927734375%

However, I have no way of knowing it is the correct answer so I'd appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

Comment: You should write $100\%$ in your calculation of the percentage, but your answer is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks!